# Google Chart show French Number value?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've used Google Chart to make good with English Number like this (float number: 98.123 and long number is: 98,123). But the problem ís that out country use French Number (float number like this: 98,123 and long number is 98.123).

So the Google Chart don't know the French Number (they consider if I use float number English (98.123) to fake French long Number (98.123). So the max value is only 100 instead of 100.000.

How can I change Google Maps to display the French Number (I think they can keep the English Number but let me replace "." to ",").

Comment: That should be handled by localization.  Try [loading the API using your locale](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#loadwithlocale).

Comment: many thanks asgallant. I'll try your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really familiar with Google Chart, but you can change the output format with the number format method :

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=fr#numberformatter

For exemple:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    decimalSymbol  : ',',
    groupingSymbol : '.'
});
formatter.format(your_data, 1);
```

decimalSymbol will change the decimal marker format.

groupingSymbol will change the separator format.

Comment: I don't know that could help me or not but many thanks for your help. I'll try.